# Problem counting items in an individual row without duplication

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to write a query that will include a count for the primary and secondary activity only when Group ID = 260 and Item id in(1302,1303,1305,1306) for each individual RecordID. So far I have been able to single out the rows with those conditions, but I only want to count the primary and secondary activities once(because the Primary and Secondary activities are the same for their corresponding RecordID regardless of how many rows there are), if they aren't null, regardless of how many RecordID's match those conditions.

```
RecordID:      GroupID:     ItemID:       PrimActivity:    SecActivity:
  320            260          1302            36                 0
  320            260          6456            36                 0 
  320            312          1303            36                 0
  560            400          1302            46                48
  560            312          1305            46                48
  460            260          1305            45                56
  460            260          1302            45                56



 Result I'm getting:
 RecordID:           Count:
   320                 2
   460                 4


 Expected result:
 RecordID:           Count:
   320                 1
   460                 2

SELECT dfr.RecordID,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN dfr.PrimActivity <> 0 and a.GroupID =260 then 1 
       ELSE NULL END) +
       COUNT(CASE WHEN dfr.SecActivity <> 0 and a.GroupID =260 then 1 ELSE 
       NULL END) AS Count
From ActivityItem ai
Join DailyRecord dfr on ai.PrimActivity = dfr.PrimActivity
Join AreaInfo af on af.AreaInfoID = dfr.AreaInfoID
Join Information a on dfr.RecordID = a.RecordID
Join Lookup lp on lp.ItemID = a.ItemID 

WHERE a.GroupID like '260' and EXISTS(
      SELECT b.RecordID, b.GroupID, b.ItemID
      FROM  Areainfo b
      where a.RecordID=b.RecordID and b.ItemID IN(1302,1303,1305,1306)
GROUP BY dfr.RecordID
```

Comment: Please explain the problem properly. Your question and your attempted query has quite a few gaps. Your question started with one table. But you involved 6 tables in your attempted query. It is important to understand the details of the underlying tables to provide proper guidance. Also, by looking at the query, quick tips: 1> You can try by putting the dfr.PrimActivity <> 0 or dfr.SecActivity <> 0 filters in where clause. 2> Use DISTINCT inside your count removing CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should be more clear when you explain the structure of tables you are using. However, I reach the expected result starting from your sample table doing this:

```
SELECT RecordID,COUNT(*) as Count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RecordID,ItemID,PrimActivity,SecActivity
      FROM [TABLE YOU POSTED]
      WHERE GroupID = 260 and ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306) ) A
GROUP BY RecordID
```